# Ways to check within an application if an instance of the application is already running?

Tags: go

I have an application that runs on a schedule.  I want the application to check if an instance of it is already running.  If there is an instance running then the application exits.  If no instance of the application is running then it continues on performing it's job.

I thought about using a lock or PID file and checking for the existence of the file.  Is there something I could do with os.Getpid() or os.Executable() and accomplish this?

Comment: your application can listen to a specific port , and for checking call that port

Comment: You could write out a file called "the pid of the running process", then read it and use it to ascertain if process is indeed still alive?  Maybe `flock`?

Comment: That's what I was thinking of doing.  I wasn't sure if there was a more idiomatic way to do it in Go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went the route of just creating a pid file and checking for that.

```
pidfile, err := os.OpenFile(watcherconfig.TeleportFileWatcher.PIDFile, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_EXCL, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        if os.IsExist(err) {
            watcherlog.InfoLogger.Println("An instance of the file watcher application is already running.")
            
            os.Exit(0)
        }
    }
    defer pidfile.Close()
```